# How can two or more lists be traversed in O(N)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, comparison

I have a question that doesn't seem possible to me. I have 2+ arrays which I have to compare for common values. I am supposed to do this in O(N) comparisons but can't think of a way. Specifically (k-1)N comparisons where k is the number of arrays. I've narrowed down how I can take multiple arrays and just merge them into a single array. I've gotten that the smallest array is the limiting factor so if I sort that I can save the most comparisons. After spending half the day staring at my screen I've even come up with a way to do this linearly if I discount any duplicates, but I have to keep duplicates So, as far as I know in order to compare any arrays you need at least 2 for loops which would be O(N^2) wouldn't it? I'm also not allowed to hash anything.

For example if I had {1,3,4,3,4,5} as a master and {1,1,3,5,9,3,7} and {3,5,8,4,0,3,2} as arrays to be compared I'd need to have a final of {3,3,5} since I can't get rid of any dupiclates.

I don't want anyone to write the code, I just need to know what I should be doing in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't sound possible to me either, if the arrays aren't sorted.

Comment: I am allowed to sort them. Do you see a way of doing it if they are??

Comment: Sorting them takes more than O(n) comparisons, though.

Comment: the sorting is allowed to happen outside of the method which compares them. Only the method that compares them for the actual final array needs to be O(N).

Comment: @Read_My_Feels991: Let me know if my method works. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are sorted, then it's relatively straightforward if you do something like this:

```
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < list1.size() && j < list2.size()) {
  int a = list1.get(i);
  int b = list2.get(j);
  if (a < b) {
    i++;
  } else if (b < a) {
    j++;
  } else { // a == b
    intersection.add(a);
    i++;
    j++;
  }
}
```

On each iteration of the loop, the quantity `i + j` increases by at least 1, and the loop is guaranteed to be done when `i + j >= list1.size() + list2.size()`, so the whole thing does at most O(list1.size() + list2.size()) comparisons.

Comment: `a < b` and `b > a` are the same condition.

Comment: The trick is how to answer it without giving the code, because it is very likely a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of ints. Taking your first list, for each element, set the value at that index to `1`. So if the first element is 3, put `1` in array[3]. Now, we know that 3 is present in first list. Putting `1` will help you distinguish from a 3 that is present in the earlier list versus a 3 which is repeated in current list.

1. Iterate through all the other k-1 lists
2. For every element, check the value in array for that index
3. If the value is 0, set it to this list number
4. If the value is a number less than this list number, this number is a duplicate and has already appeared in a previous list.
5. If this number is equal to this list index it means this number already occurred in this list but not in previous lists, so not yet a duplicate.
6. The numbers that you are getting as duplicates, add them to another list.
7. Finish all iterations

Finally print the duplicates.

---

**Original Wrong Answer**

1. Create a `HashSet<int>`
2. Take all values from master and add to it - O(master list count)
3. Now just iterate through first and second arrays and see if their elements are in that HashSet - O(each list count)

Comment: Question specifically states "I'm also not allowed to hash anything."

Comment: You're using indexing, which is essentially a do-it-yourself hashing method. This would be a good method if the original values were all confined to a small integer range. It's clear that the OP is being asked a question by an instructor who is trying to teach the merge method.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: I don't know of this merge method that will help find duplicates in linked lists in O(N). Can you give me some link to it?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: I know this approach is better if we have a smaller range of numbers to work with, but I wanted to keep the solution as general as possible.

Comment: Merging is a basic pattern. Suppose you have two separate decks of cards, each one already sorted within itself. You look at the top card on each deck. If one is less than the other, you discard it, but not the other. If both are the same, you have a match, so you take both and put them on the match pile. This takes no more time than the number of cards. If you keep all the cards, the result is sorted. (If you do it recursively, you have the merge-sort algorithm. (my favorite))

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: But you require sorted list for that. OP's example above has unsorted elements.

Comment: The 4th comment says the arrays are sorted outside. I know he should have said it in the question.